# development and distribution certificates for iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, icloud

I am having some troubles to use iCloud within my mac application.  Following what apple [said](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/CodeSigning/CodeSigning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011201-CH7-SW1) to their web site :

***Important**: You set the Code Signing Identity build setting for the project, not for any of the individual targets.*

I tried the 4 following scenarios in XCode 4.2.1 :

1. Set the distribution certificate/profile into the project build setting.
   *Result* : the application starts properly, but my iCloud is not called
2. Set the distribution certificate/profile into the application target build setting.
   *Result* : the application starts, but after few seconds, seems to be killed or something.  Very bad!
3. Set the development certificate/profile into the project build setting.
   *Result* : The application starts properly, but iCloud is not working!
4. Set the development certificate/profile into the application target build setting.
   *Result* : The application starts properly and i am able to use iCloud!!!

There is only one case where i am able to use iCloud.  So i have 2 questions :

**Questions :**

1. **What is the difference between setting  certificate to project versus application target**
2. **Why i am not able to use iCloud when i do sign with distribution certificate?  I really need to make that working to be sure that i can distribute my application to the mac store.**

Thank you

Comment: For question 1, Xcode automatically sets the application setting when I checked "Code Sign Application" checkbox. It may be a documentation error. For question 2, I think that development certificate is for testing, and distribution certificate is ONLY for the store.

Comment: It is kind of a huge error!  On the apple web page, it is written "Important" in bold!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case people might be interested, i have found the answer of my question number 2 :

If you go to the Organizer, and click on the distribution profile, you will see a message like that : *Devices This profile cannot be installed on devices*

In other words, you can install the distribution profile in organizer, but not into your system profile.  The result is you can build your code in XCode, but the application will **not** start, because it checks the profile in your system profile.